# Java Encrypting a Caesar code

Tags: java

I'm new to java, and having trouble using Strings and Character assignment, when
they intertwined. Here the Caesar program doesn't run because the assignment between
Character and String have to be compared. Please help
thank you.

```
class Caesar {
    public static char encrypt(String str) {
        String result = "";
        String x;
        for (String ch : str) {
            x = plainalphabet.indexOf(ch);
            if (x != -1) {
                result = result + cipheralphabet.charAt(x);
            }
            else {
                result = result + ch;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String plainalphabet  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String cipheralphabet = "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc";
        System.out.println(encrypt("James"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the error you're getting, and the line you're getting it on.

Comment: `cipheralphabet` is not defined in the scope of `encrypt`. You might want to read about variables scopes

Comment: `for (String ch : str)` is an enhanced-for statement.  Whatever you're using that on has to implement `Iterable`.  You'd be better off using a standard `for` loop anyway (both because of syntax errors, and you want to use the index in your iteration anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible fix:

```
public class Caesar {
    private static final String PLAIN = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // fix scope

    private static final String CIPHER = "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc"; // fix scope

    public static String encrypt(String str)
    {
        String result = "";
        int x; // indexOf returns int
        for (final char ch : str.toCharArray()) { // str is not an Iterable
            x = PLAIN.indexOf(ch);
            if (x != -1) {
                result = result + CIPHER.charAt(x);
            } else {
                result = result + ch;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(encrypt("James"));
    }
}
```

(community wiki, as it's barely an answer, to what's barely a question)

Comment: change to: for (char ch : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray())  <--- J in James doesnt translate.

Comment: For a minor speedup, instead of   `x=PLAIN.indexOf(ch)`, could just subtract,  `x = ch - 'a'`;   Assuming ASCII (and that you converted to lowercase)...

Comment: guys, just edit and fix/change it ;) The real algo would have been string => char => shift => string

Answer (score 0):

First of all the signature should be changed to

```
public static String encrypt(String str)
```

And instead of for (String ch : str) use

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

Comment: No no no; not `i <= str.length()`; it's `i < str.length()`.  Huge difference.